# Read the incoming url after adding a redirection rule on server

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have added a redirection rule on the domino server like this:

```
Incoming URL pattern: /xxx/*
Replacement pattern: /myDb.nsf/myXpage.xsp
```

How is it possible from the xpage to read the incoming url in the browser?

If I open this url:

```
"http://myDomain/xxx/test"
```

Then I get redirected to my xpage and if I do context.getUrl() i got

```
"http://myDomain/myDb.nsf/myXpage.xsp"
```

but is there an option to read the incoming url?

```
"http://myDomain/xxx/test"
```

Comment: I don't think you can see the original URL since the request is probably redirected before XPages takes over. Why do you want to see the original URL and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use clean url, if every request to /xxx/* goes to my xpage, then the xpage based on the incomming url will decide which document to open.

Comment: What will your XPage use to decide which doc to open? the part after /xxx/ (so that for instance /xxx/test opens the 'test' document)?

Comment: Yes, it will then open the test document

Comment: OK, you then need to transfer /xxx/* to your XPage

Comment: Have you checked what 's inside the HTTP header of the incoming request?

Comment: Yes, and I cant find anything to use. I have added a new questions to see if someone know if its possible to add a new header variable that could be a calculated CGI value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167609/domino-server-internet-rule-http-response-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ýou can change your replacement pattern to

```
/myDb.nsf/myXpage.xsp/xxx/*
```

This allows you to access the part between the *.xsp* and the query parameters with

```
facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestPathInfo()
```

F.e.

```
"http://myDomain/xxx/test"
```

would give you

```
"/xxx/test"
```

Comment: wow, I expected this to redirect to a broken link but it work like a charm:) Sorry for not have enough "reputation" to vote you up, but hopefully all other will do that.

Comment: Perfect, easy and robust solution, work with "?" in the url also.

Answer (score 1):

The browser can still get the original url so could you put the following the in the Client JS event, onClientLoad to redirect the user to the XPage with the right url parameters to properly provide the url parameter?

```
mystring = window.location.href;
var rightback = mystring.substring(mystring.lastIndexOf("/")+1,mystring.length);
window.location.href = "/test.nsf/testurl1.xsp?openxpage&id=" + rightback;
```

Comment: This is not the robust solution I was looking for. If the user is typing in the address the server needs to generate a dummy page with javascript that goes back to this page back to the server with the url as parameter?

Comment: I didn't say it was robust! You need to create two XPages. The first one will just have the code I had above to redirect to the second XPage that will actually display your content using the parameter.

Comment: ok it was creative solution, but it has too many drawback. Google will not index the page, you mess upp the history back button in the browser. And the code will not be able to work properly if the url contains #

Answer (score 0):

Change your redirection rule to include *:

```
Incoming URL pattern: /xxx/*
Replacement pattern: /myDb.nsf/myXpage.xsp?id=*
```

This way you can read the * part of your URL in your XPage using `param.get("id")` and then use that variable to find and open the relevant document.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but then its not possible to use parameter in the url. 
Example:
http://myDomain/xxx/test?param=123. Domino seems to ignore everything after the "?". I have also tried the substitution rule. Incoming Url: /xxx/*?*, replacement pattern: /myDb.nsf/myXpage.xsp?id=*&* But again domino ignore the the char "?". It's so strange because it work when using "!", but I don't like to use "!" for parameter in url. Is this a bug in Domino?

Comment: A no domino, xpages knowledged guy's suggestion: If actually what you are attempting is an HTTP redirection, see if you have a url rewriting ability to direct all requests to server script (xsp?). In the rewriting rule, even get the path, parameters to be a new parameter (like /index.xsp?q=originalpath/../&originalparam1&originalparam2). Now in the script (may be index.xsp?), form the original url in the way you want, encode the original url, add to the target url as a parameter and make the HTTP redirection. Make sure the final URL is not too lengthy (some proxies and so on impose limits).

Comment: The domino server has it own simple GUI for adding http rules. But I know that domino has it a more advanced approach using DSAPI written in C to manipulate the the http server, but I was hoping not use that.