# Domino server internet rule "HTTP response headers"

Tags: lotus-domino

When creating a "HTTP response headers" rule on a Domino server there is an option for "Customer Header".
The description of this field says:

```
(HTTP Response Header only) For each custom header you want to use, specify:

"Name" - files in the directory are displayed in the browser or downloaded.    
"Value" - files in the directory are CGI files to be executed on the server.    
"Override" -  (override application's header)
```

In the "Value" field it says something about CGI, so my question is:

Is it possible to add some CGI variable or script in this value field or do it only accepts pure strings?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you ask... the value is a string whi can contain also True or number as string. Theorically you can enter in this string the code of a script BUT I never seen this. Don't forget you need to assign this value to a parameter name, a cgi variable.

Comment: My question is if it's possible to run some kind of script in the value field and not only typing a string.

Comment: The code will be served AS TEXT by the server, the server will not execute it. I guessed you've been fooled by the CGI term: it doesn't means that on server side a program (your code) will run.

Comment: Ok, you should write is as an answered so I could close the question.

Comment: I came across this strange pop-up help to day. It is clearly not related to the issue at hand, and most probably has been copy-pasted by the domino designers from another form to be updated, but was forgotten in its current malformed state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will be served AS TEXT by the server, the server will not execute it.

I guessed you've been fooled by the CGI term: it does **not** means that on server side a program (your code) will run.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Redbooks%3A+Best+Practices+for+Domino+8.0+Web+Application+Development#action=openDocument&res_title=07252008102848AMKMKJYL.htm&content=pdcontent